# Variable dimension fluid images, vertically and horizontally centered

Tags: css, firefox, vertical-alignment

http://www.publicgathering.net/temp/fluidvert.html

Interestingly enough the problem here is in Firefox of all things.

Single image per page, variable heights and widths, has to be vertically and horizontally centered, has to be fluid (shrinks for smaller browser windows) and I'm merely looking for recent browser support (IE8, Chrome, FF3, Safari)

The image should resize (smaller) based on the width of the browser.

It works fine in IE8, Chrome and Safari but not FF. I realize its because FF isn't registering the width properly. (For instance you put the image in a 100% wide div and that's fine.) Simply using a real table doesn't work either.

Is there a way to force Firefox to recognize the width of the table/div? Or a simpler way to vertically center variable content?

On another note: Does anyone find it strange that this is FF's default behavior in this situation?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it reliably in CSS, but there is a way to do it in about 4 lines of javascript.

Comment: Ok well that could work. What do you recommend?

Comment: What exactly is it that is not working? The sizing, the vertical centering or the horizontal centering?

Comment: And you're basing it off of this example? http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-horizontal-align-valid-solution-en.html

Comment: The fluid resizing images is what isn't working. I'm setting the image to max-width:100%; and the containing div is set to width:100%; so that it resizes smaller in accordance with a smaller browser window. It isn't working in FF because I'm assuming it isn't recognizing the width of the containing div because it's displaying as a table. As I said this also doesn't work with real tables.

Comment: @Breakthrough yes. Although in the one you linked to uses a fixed width content div. Mine is dependent on the browser window (i.e. 100% wide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307866

That answers that question. Still a bug in FF3.5 yet reported in late 2005.